# .Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages - How to pass a controller to a Partial View in the Layout Page?

Tags: partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

In my layout.cshtml razor page, razor will automatically use the index.cshtml.cs file as its page model.

Within the layout page I have an partial view tag helper pointing to my separate partial view page.

```
<partial name="_AlarmListPartial" />
```

In my partial view called _AlarmListPartial, I want to process server side methods in a separate controller, which I already have called "AlarmListController.cs"

How do configure the partial page to use the controller, rather than expecting to use/inherit the page model index.cshtml file?

I've tried including the detail of the model in the partial page tag helper but get the squiggly lines:

```
<partial name="_AlarmListPartial" model="MyProject.Controllers.AlarmListController"/>
```

Message = "AlarmListController is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

I assume I need to include something at the top of the controller page such as @model something...

None of the partial page guides are making any sense to me.

Comment: If your partial involves some server-side processing of logic, you should consider a View Component instead: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components.

Comment: Yeah I went down this route in the end, thanks